# Java FTP file says it was uploaded but does not appear on the server

Tags: java, file, upload, ftp

I'm attempting to create and write to a file from a program to an `FTP` file server. The `.getReply()` method gives

> "226-File successfully transferred."

Despite this, the file does not show up on the server about 95% of the time. It occasionally does work, but very rarely. I have not been able to identify a specific trend of when it does and does not upload.

```
try{
    String userName = "";

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    client.connect("host", 21);
    boolean login = client.login("username", "password");
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

    String remoteFile = "/scores/";  
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    userName = read.readLine();
    File localStore = new File(dir + "\\results\\" + userName + ".txt");
    localStore.getParentFile();
    localStore.createNewFile();
    FileWriter write = new FileWriter(localStore);
    String br = "BREAK";
    write.write(cpuName);
    write.write(br);
    write.write(CPUs);
    write.write(br);
    write.write(gpuName + " x" + gpuAmt);
    write.write(br);
    write.write(mbInfo);
    write.write(br);
    write.write(os);
    write.write(br);
    write.write(finalScore);
    write.close();
    if (login){
        String userdetail = "/scores/" + userName + ".txt";
        System.out.println(userName);
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(localStore);
        boolean a = client.storeFile(userdetail, input);
        this.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(client.getReplyString());
        input.close();
        client.logout();    
        client.disconnect();
    }
}catch (Exception err){}
```

I greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your catch you doesn't nothing. Add code at least to log what happens if an exception is thrown.

Probably an exception has been thrown but you don't know that.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: No because this is the road to solve the problem. So it is an answer.

Comment: No exceptions are ever thrown after numerous tries.